# How to display time from a media played from the javascript file, into a html file

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a mp3 located inside cordova.file.dataDirectory;

I'm playing it through the javascript file with media.play(); when the user presses the play button. I now wan't to display the time (how much seconds the media is already played.)

This is not my complete code just assume that the media is played.

```
media.play();

media.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    // Display the current position of the mp3 in a p element with id="time"
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = media.currentTime;
}
```

I want to display the time inside the html here:

```
<p>Playback position:<span id="time"></span></p>
```

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code after playing the media

```
 if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {

                media.getCurrentPosition(

                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = position;
                        }
                    },

                    function(e) {
                        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Error";
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks it works, with obviously first setting up the mediaTimer variable and then making a few changes for example I used  <div class="time" id="time"></div> instead of  <p>Playback position:<span id="time"></span></p> and I assigned it into javascript with  $time = document.querySelector("#time"); In your code I just changed document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = position; into $time.innerHTML = position;  Thanks again :)